# Why does Next.js install both Typescript and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

When I run this command `npx create-next-app --typescript --example with-tailwindcss my_project` my project end up looking like this:

[image]

How can I install Next.js with Typescript and Tailwindcss without the Javascript files?

Comment: What is your question? You've asked two here.

Comment: @kelly My question is how to install Next.js with Typescript and Tailwindcss at once without having .js files.

Comment: `npx create-next-app --example with-tailwindcss my_project` should work. The Next.js Tailwind CSS example is in TypeScript by default.

Comment: @juliomalves That's what I said in answer.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this official Git repo [Next.js + Tailwind CSS Example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss) you need to run `npx create-next-app --example with-tailwindcss with-tailwindcss-app` or `npx create-next-app --example with-tailwindcss your-app-name-here`